# How to Move content to next page in WPF Form

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am new in WPF if there is something wrong please co-operate.Here i require some idea from experts.

I am working on one application in which i have to show some content on WPF form after filling the fields present on the form.On the same form i also have a print option.

Check this image.This is my form here part in the red block is generated at runtime.When i click on the print button it only show the visible part on the paper and skip the remaining part.

[image: WPF Form]

**Problem :**
How i can move the remaining part of the form which is under scroll to next page when i click on print.

**For example** in the given image we can see only 2 bulls eye completely and next 2 partially.How i can shift this remaining part to next page only **when i click on print**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow [this](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=nYl7J7z3KssC&pg=PA998&lpg=PA998&dq=documentpaginator%20wpf%20c#&source=bl&ots=V530noZ27x&sig=5WLG-ef7N0bmWchkVsTTVDJla-A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2WkjULT9H8qIrAequIGYAQ&ved=0CF0Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=documentpaginator%20wpf%20c#&f=true) link.This is the basic which i got after searching in web world.Using this basic detail you can do any thing with print in WPF

Answer (score 2):

The answer is quite easy : don't rely on your window to do the printing, but build the visual you want then print it.
For instance, you must have a function that creates dynamically the circles and so on, then adds them to a Panel. What you might do is to print the Panel.
Or if you prefer, you might build Dynamically a new window, where you put all the Data you want printed as you want, then print the window. The advantage of this method is that it is more flexible for the content (if you want a header/footer) and also you can watch the content easily for debug. Note that even if the Window content is dynamic, you can have a base window for printing that avoids you to do too much xaml with code (expl : you might have TextBox bound to a PrintTitle property that you setup in the constructor of the Print Window...).
Notice that visual that were not rendered on screen will not print. Be sure, to avoid the common issues, to have a look at this article from this great site, switch on the code, here :
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/printing-in-wpf

Edit (reply to the question in comment):
1) If you have fixed number of bulls eyes, just make one Window for that number and Print it, this is waaaay easier.
2) To put Visuals in pages instead of rows, you'll have to rely on page Width/Height. What matters is the size of your control vs size of page. In the example, they build (in OnRender) Controls having LineHeight, LineWidth as size. Do the same : Try to put as many line of control as you can such as 
      (Control Height + margin )*NumberOfControlPerPage < Page Height.
Then you have to change OnRender to render controls instead of Rows made with rectangle+text. Pack your controls two by two in Horizontal StackPanels Then pack those StackPanel into a vertical StackPanel, then render. You have to keep track for each page which control was rendered last, then resume rendering at the following control.

Comment: Thanks Vincent for this link.I am looking in http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-printing-part-2-pagination.
Can you tell me how i can add usercontrol instead of rows?

Comment: Thanks @Vincent for help.Finally i got answer.Again thanks a lot